# Magento category page white screen- php memory limit

Tags: memory

We have two websites sharing same catalog but different prices. Total catalog size is 10K. Site1 displays products/categories fine. However same category on **site2** shows "white Screen of Death". After inspecting server log we get following error

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes)

Php memory limit is set to 512. We also changed to 1024MB but no joy

Surprisingly, when we move catalog folder out of Media, category loads fine with place holder image

**If image size is the issue, then I am struggling to understand Why same products/images work fine on site1.
 
Magento re-size and cache images so using one large size image should not effect.

Both Sites use same template/catalog/product/list.phtml**

Please share your experience or dont shy to give advice.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any different between the two list template? Are you loading resource in a loop?

Comment: It may looks that PHP is not using memory_limit value you set. 268435456 from fatal error is 256MB. Recommended setting is at least 512MB, try to check phpinfo output to make sure your change had an effect.

Comment: @WojtekNaruniec this could be an answer tbh

Comment: @ToonVanDooren Thanks for pointing that, just did that.

Answer (score 1):

It may looks that PHP is not using memory_limit value you set. 268435456 from fatal error is 256MB. Recommended setting is at least 512MB, try to check phpinfo output to make sure your change had an effect.